# MFC tooltip for list control of dialog box

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, mfc, tooltip

I have developed on application, which shows a dialog box with two list controls.
In this list control, I am showing images. Now I want is, when we move the mouse on images from the list control of dialog box, It will show tool tip for that.

How can I show tool tips for images in a list control in a dialog box?

Comment: Are you using a listbox or listview control?

Answer (score 4):

The [`CToolTipCtrl` control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6b4cb3a5.aspx) is the MFC wrapper class around the Win32 "tool tip". You can use this to display a small pop-up window to describe another control or provide additional information in your app.

If you're using a ListBox control, explore one of these sample projects to see how to display tooltips for individual items displayed within that ListBox control:

- [ListBox With ToolTip Support](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/combobox/cexlistboc.aspx)
- [List Box With ToolTips](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/combobox/ttlistboxdemo.aspx)

And if you're using a ListView control ([`CListCtrl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hfshke78.aspx) in MFC), then you should start by reading the documentation for the [`GetToolTips` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hyx3x0yx.aspx) and the corresponding [`SetToolTips` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h550e2a8.aspx). You can also check out how this sample ListView control implements tooltips:

- [CListCtrl and Displaying a Tooltip](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/list/CListCtrl_ToolTip.aspx)