# Setting tooltip text for CListCtrl control in VC++

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, mfc

I have a CListCtrl in my MFC project. I want to set tooltip text for each row in that CListCtrl control.

I did some googling and coded it. Following is my code

```
CListCtrl *pLCComp = (CListCtrl*)GetDlgItem(IDC_LC_COMPONENTS);
RECT rect;
UINT id;
BOOL bRes;
for (size_t i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        n = pLCComp->InsertItem(i, c_Functions[i]);
        pLCComp->GetItemRect(n, &rect, LVIR_BOUNDS);
        id = pLCComp->MapIndexToID((UINT)(n));
        id++;
        bRes = pTooltip->AddTool(pLCComp, c_FuncToolTip[i], &rect, id);
    }
pTooltip->Activate(TRUE);
```

BUT the problem is, it doesn't shows tooltips.
If we skip 3rd and 4th parameters from pTooltip->AddTool() then it shows tooltip text but same text for all items in that list control.
Note : that same text is the last text in c_FuncToolTip[] array.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MFC tooltip for list control of dialog box](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6633881/mfc-tooltip-for-list-control-of-dialog-box)

Comment: @rrirower the link you provided didn't helped me.

Comment: Did you check this link? http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28885/CListCtrl-and-Displaying-a-Tooltip